# How to get count Value from Using where condition

Tags: mysql, group-by

```
select count(*) total, sum(case when stu_community = 'BC' then 1 else 0 
end) bc, b.branch_name FROM admission_details a, stu_personal_details p,
stu_contact_details c, current_course curr,degree d, courses co, branch 
b WHERE a.admission_no = p.admission_no AND p.stu_rollno = c.stu_rollno 
AND c.stu_rollno = curr.stu_rollno AND curr.stu_rollno = p.stu_rollno 
AND (curr.stu_branch IN (18,19,20) AND d.degree_id = curr.stu_degree AND
co.course_id = curr.stu_course AND b.branch_id = curr.stu_branch)
```

The above query provided following result set 

[image]

but

i want count value from each branch AND Each community in same query it can possible? i want result like this [image]

what can i do? pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `group by` function to get the expected result

at the end of your query add

```
 group by b.branch_name
```

Comment: @BalakumarB,  kindly accept the answer, which is the tick button below the votes